# Creating a installer for my PHP scripts

Tags: php, mysql, installation

I'm currently buizy with a PHP website script, so the base for any other CMS, website, etc. Because alot of newbies are goin' to use it I want to make a install.php, only problem: I don't know how... Can anyone help me?

I want people to run it and the script than runs a SQL file, the user makes a admin account etc. So any help would be great.

I already read a ton of questions on this subject but the most are outdated, so I thought that it wasn't good to use outdated PHP...

Thanks.

Comment: stackoverflow is made to get help on your script. not to ask people to create one for you. I'm quite sure there are some tutorials that can teach you what you want in parts if you have knowledge in php and sql. EDIT: you can take a look at these http://www.apphp.com/php-easyinstaller/ http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpappinstaller/

Answer (score 0):

Make a Install.php with a form Asking for database connection details, then perform following action-

1. Validate that the script will run (Files & database permission)
2. Install i.e create all db and tables etc.
3. Make sure the folder/files/database structure isn't already present (if the script has run before)

THere are tutorials available like [this](http://tutsforweb.blogspot.in/2012/02/php-installation-script.html)